LM358P as a voltage follower doesn't work as expected
I'm trying to implement a voltage follower using op-amp LM358P
I've got two voltage dividers (group of resistors)
Input voltage: ~4V
The first group of resistors work as expected: the voltage across the voltage divider is similar to the output voltage of the op-amp (LM358P) (voltage divider output: ~1.94V, op-amp output: ~2.0V)
Second bunch of resistors has unequal voltages (voltage divider output: ~3.2V, op-amp output ~2.69V)
What could be the problem?



What's your power supply voltage?

Power supply voltage is 4V

Note the "Output Voltage−High Limit" spec from the data sheet, adjust for your supply voltage.

In TI's LM358 datasheet page 6, section 6.3 Recommended operating conditions, it lists the maximum common mode voltage as Vcc-2. Since your Vcc is 4 V, an input of 3.2 V is outside of the recommended operating conditions. It is therefore not guaranteed to operate correctly. In short, your op-amp is saturating.

Thanks a lot. I know this little bit out of scope of this question, but maybe you can recommend me some op-amp that suits my case (4V input voltage and 3V op-amp output) As far as I understand,  "common-mode input voltage"  in this case should be VCC -1

I replaced LM358P to NE5532 and it seems work now.
